# Laravel error when installing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just installed Laravel through Homestead and I tried to access the page and it gives me these errors:

```
( ! ) Warning: require(/home/vagrant/sites/connected/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/sites/connected/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  355664  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0002  355912  require( '/home/vagrant/sites/connected/bootstrap/autoload.php' )   .../index.php:22

( ! ) Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/vagrant/sites/connected/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:') in /home/vagrant/sites/connected/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  355664  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0002  355912  require( '/home/vagrant/sites/connected/bootstrap/autoload.php' )   .../index.php:22
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have forgotten to install the dependencies with Composer. In the root directory of your project (where the `composer.json` file is) do a

```
composer install
```

and then `vendor/autoload.php` will exist.

Comment: What directory should I do it in?

Comment: In the root directory of your project, where the `composer.json` file is.

Comment: I did `composer install` and it downloaded the vendor file and it's contents but not `autoload.php`

Comment: `vendor` is a directory and it should contain `autoload.php` - are you saying this is not the case after you ran `composer install`?

Comment: Exactly. Don't know why.

Comment: Hmm... can you edit your question to include the `composer.json` file?

Comment: @C.Pantelli Try running `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

please update your composer using this command or re-install composer.

```
`composer update`
```